# DexArchiveMergerException : transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug

Tags: android, gradle-dependencies, android-gradle-3.0

**Android 3.0.1**

I got problem with DexArchiveMergerException and I found out that this is a problem with libraries (implementation, compile). But I couldn't find which one to fix. I tried to clean and rebuild.

This is my build.gradle.
What could I do with my dependencies?
Thanks a lot :)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.scsa.project"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.9.3'
    implementation 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:2.0.0.M3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

Comment: Look in the Gradle Console for a Java stack trace with details of exactly what the merger error was.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for letting me know :) I tried and get result of saying "Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;"

Comment: @CommonsWare so, i got the problem is with com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson but didn't get which one to fix :(

Comment: Well, one copy of that should come from the Jackson dependencies. Maybe `org.simpleframework:simple-xml` or one of the `org.springframework.android` dependencies is pulling in another copy. You can poke around these dependencies in the "External Libraries" section of the project tree.

Comment: @CommonsWare Problem solved :) Thank you so much. I used "External Libraries" and implementation at the same time.